# Avoid duplicate data in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Good morning I have the following question, how can I validate that the record is not duplicated in my datagridview.

this is my code to send data from gridview list to gridview details

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim rowSelected As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvlistarproductos.Rows
        Dim cellSelecion As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = TryCast(row.Cells("SELECCIONAR"), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

        If Convert.ToBoolean(cellSelecion.Value) Then
            rowSelected.Add(row)
        End If
    Next

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In rowSelected
        
            dgvdetalleproduc.Rows.Add(New Object() {row.Cells(1).Value, row.Cells(2).Value
                                                    })
    Next



End Sub
```

[image]

Any suggestion or help I know I have to validate but I don't know where to place it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both of you for giving me an idea of ​​how to solve this case.

I managed to solve and detect if the selected record is repeated or duplicated when passing to the Datagridview with the following code

```
   Dim existe = False
    Dim rowSelected As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvlistarproductos.Rows
        Dim cellSelecion As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = TryCast(row.Cells("SELECCIONAR"), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

        If Convert.ToBoolean(cellSelecion.Value) Then
            rowSelected.Add(row)
        End If
    Next

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvdetalleproduc.Rows
        If Convert.ToString(row.Cells(0).Value).Equals(dgvlistarproductos.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value) Then
            existe = True
        End If
    Next


    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In rowSelected
        If (existe = True) Then
            MsgBox("ESTE PRODUCTO YA FUE AGREGADO", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "INFORMACIÓN")

        Else
            dgvdetalleproduc.Rows.Add(New Object() {row.Cells(1).Value, row.Cells(2).Value
                                                                })
        End If

    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to just have both grids use a single data source(datatable) for their info and have a Boolean column in the datatable like "isChosen". Each grid binds to a separate bindingsource or dataview, one of which has its [Row]Filter set to `"[isChosen] = True"`, the other filters for false. The `>>` button sets the selected row(s)' ischosen to true, the other button sets it false

Because there is only ever one row, and it doesn't "move" anywhere (it just appears in a different grid depending on the value of isChosen) there are no duplicates

To demonstrate this:

- make a new form
- put two datagridview on it
- put two buttons on it
- put this code in the constructor after InitializeComponent:

```
    Dim dt as New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns.Add("IsChosen", GetType(Boolean))
    dt.Rows.Add("John", False)
    dt.Rows.Add("Mark", False)
    dt.Rows.Add("Luke", False)

    Dim bs1 = New BindingSource()
    bs1.Filter = "[IsChosen] = False"
    bs1.DataSource = dt
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs1

    Dim bs2 = New BindingSource()
    bs2.Filter = "[IsChosen] = True"
    bs2.DataSource = dt
    dataGridView2.DataSource = bs2
```

- double click button1 and put code `DirectCast(DirectCast(dataGridView1.DataSource, BindingSource).Current, DataRowView)("IsChosen") = True`
- double click button2 and put code `DirectCast(DirectCast(dataGridView2.DataSource, BindingSource).Current, DataRowView)("IsChosen") = False`

Run the app, click on a name in dgv1 and click button1, it will move to dgv2

You can also toggle the state of the ✅ checkbox column in the grid and it will move - it doesn't matter how the datatable column comes to be True/False to move the row into dgv 2/1 respectively

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your validation code in the RowValidating event of the DataGridView control, or try this code below:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim rowSelected As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvlistarproductos.Rows
        Dim cellSelecion As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = TryCast(row.Cells("SELECCIONAR"), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

        If Convert.ToBoolean(cellSelecion.Value) Then
            rowSelected.Add(row)
        End If
    Next
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In rowSelected
        If dgvdetalleproduc.Rows.Contains(row) = False Then
            dgvdetalleproduc.Rows.Add(New Object() {row.Cells(1).Value, row.Cells(2).Value})
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If `IDPRODUCTO` means *unique product ID* as it sounds then use it to identify and skip the duplicates thru a LINQ query like so:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim checkedRows = dgvlistarproductos.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
        Where(Function(r1) r1.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Convert.ToBoolean(r1.Cells(0).Value)).
        Where(Function(r1) Not dgvdetalleproduc.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
        Any(Function(r2) r2.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso r2.Cells(0).Value.ToString().
        Equals(r1.Cells(1).ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))

    For Each row In checkedRows
        dgvdetalleproduc.Rows.Add(row.Cells(1).Value, row.Cells(2).Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

You can use the columns names rather than their indices to get the cells values.